# Converting string to float - ValueError: invalid literal for float()

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

**My problem:**

I'm using selenium to capture some values of a specific field and trying to convert these values to float

**My code:**

```
self.get_oral_exams_amount_value = float(self.driver.find_element(EventsLocators.ORAL_EXAMS_AMOUNT).text)
self.get_bitewings_amount_value = float(self.driver.find_element(EventsLocators.BITEWINGS_AMOUNT).text)
self.get_noshow_amount_value = float(self.driver.find_element(EventsLocators.NOSHOW_AMOUNT).text)
```

**My error:**

```
self.get_oral_exams_amount_value = float(self.driver.find_element(EventsLocators.ORAL_EXAMS_AMOUNT).text)
```

> ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 3,629.50

How can I do this conversion correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get rid of `','`.

```
self.get_oral_exams_amount_value = float(self.driver.find_element(EventsLocators.ORAL_EXAMS_AMOUNT).text.replace(",", ""))
```

With `replace(",", "")` your initial string `'3,629.50'` will result in `'3629.50'` which can be converted to float.

Comment: Thanks. Worked fine!

Comment: Now I have a new problem `self.get_shipping_fee_amount_value = float(self.find_element(EventsLocators.PANO_SHIPPING_FEE_AMOUNT).text.replace(",", ""))` returning `ValueError: could not convert string to float:` Any idea?

Comment: Show us the string you are getting

Comment: I meant the result of executing the instruction above without converting to float. It will return a string, what string?

Comment: but I'm just trying to capture this value above and store in a variable

Comment: That question is different from what you posted